# How to do a script to read keyboard taps

Tags: python, python-2.7, raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi3

I would like to do a script that would be able to read the taps from another keyboard. That script would run at the start, then I couldn't use **raw_input**           at its own.

Thank you in advance

Comment: Hi Nico.  I strongly recommend you go to learn how to ask a complete question at this link: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Stack Overflow isn't meant to be a code completion site for people.  Please post what you've tried, some sample code, any errors you are getting, what you've found doing research, etc..

Answer (score 0):

The only way i know to do this is to `from turtle import *`, which will import the turtle graphics module, which will allow you to use `listen()`, `onkey()`, and more... the syntax for onkey is `onkey("FUNCTION", "KEY")`